# Prevent background service from being killed due to "detect excessive cpu on forked process"

Tags: android, native, syncthing

I am debugging an [issue](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-android/issues/634) of the [Syncthing Android](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing-android) wrapper. The Android application wraps a native binary of the Syncthing project and provides some additional functionality like starting/stopping based on connecting WiFi, power, etc.

Unfortunately, there have been issues about the service not auto-starting on WiFi change anymore, especially with handsets that have been upgraded to Android 6. Since my personal handset has been upgraded to 6.0.1 recently, I finally am able to debug into the issue and today I noticed the following:

```
07-06 20:52:26.562  1181  1363 I ActivityManager: [BgDetect]chkExcessCpu doKills: true uptime: 300309
07-06 20:52:26.960  1181  1363 I ActivityManager: [BgDetect]detect excessive cpu on forked process libsyncthing.so(pid : 2758) plan to stop it 371060 during 300309
07-06 20:52:26.960  1181  1363 I ActivityManager: [BgDetect]force stop com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.debug (uid 10132)
07-06 20:52:26.965  1181  1363 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.debug appid=10132 user=0: from pid 1181
07-06 20:52:26.966  1181  1363 I ActivityManager: Killing 1360:com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.debug/u0a132 (adj 15): stop com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.debug
07-06 20:52:26.968  1181  1363 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.debug/com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.syncthing.SyncthingService in 1000ms
07-06 20:52:26.968  1181  1354 V ActivityManager: killProcessGroupAsync took 1 ms for PID 1360 on thread 14
07-06 20:52:26.971  1181  6410 I libprocessgroup: Killing pid 2758 in uid 10132 as part of process group 1360
07-06 20:52:26.973  1181  6410 I libprocessgroup: Killing pid 2758 in uid 10132 as part of process group 1360
07-06 20:52:26.974  1181  1363 I ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{47304c8 u0 com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.debug/com.nutomic.syncthingandroid.syncthing.SyncthingService}
```

The Syncthing protocol is quite heavy on the CPU side, regarding encryption, hashing, etc. So it seems that the service is force-stopped due to the high CPU demands of the forked native binary.

The application is already marked as "No battery optimization", but still it is being killed. Is there a way to prevent the `ActivityManager` from killing the application due to the CPU demands of the forked process?

Comment: Hmm, a grep for `BgDetect` over the 6.0 branch of AOSP didn't return anything, so it _might_ be an addition of OxygenOS.

Comment: It seems, promoting the service to "foreground" with `startForeground()` mitigates the problems. But I consider this not a optimal solution.

Comment: Adding startForeground() does not solve this issue unfortunately

Comment: still killed by system even using startForeground()

Comment: The solution / explanation is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612307/foreground-notification-service-not-working-in-one-plus-devices/56195214#56195214

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is a OnePlus / OxygenOS feature that will kill any background process based on who-knows what rules in order to give the appearance of a better battery life.

For now, I found a non-code workaround in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdguardForAndroid/issues/1385#issuecomment-351115514) that seems to help, but is far from ideal: [pin/lock the application on the recents screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGArc.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Was testing my foreground service and realized it was a performance issue mainly CPU. So I enforced performance with the profiler and added to the white list.

Reduced the consumption cpu, ram and battery and its done.

[Foreground notification service not working in one plus devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612307/foreground-notification-service-not-working-in-one-plus-devices/56195214#56195214)