# Foreground Service Stopself after hours working

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, service

I did a Foreground Service using Kotlin. It's works , but after seven hours running my service stop and my app returned to its first page (login page). But the only method to stop my service is executed when I click in a "stop service" button, so why my service is stopping after 7 hours if i didn't press any button? i'm using a moto g7, android 9.0

```
class RastreioService : Service() {

companion object {
    var serviceAtivado = false //service activated
}
override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    serviceAtivado = true

    val notificationIntent = Intent(this, RastreioService::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    val notification = Notification.Builder(this, "1")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gps_ativo)
        .setContentTitle("Localização Sendo Acessada")
        .setContentText("A sua localização está sendo acessada")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .build()

    startForeground(1, notification)

    /*request location methods*/
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    serviceAtivado = false
    super.onDestroy()
    this.gerenciadorDeLocalizacao.DesativarBuscaPorLocalizaca()
}

}
```

Comment: Which device you are using? this device is having stock or custom ROM.
look out this answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425222/foreground-service-getting-killed-from-oreo

Comment: i'm using a moto g7, android 9.0

Comment: Is there any option in device setting like an Auto startup or battery optimization?
If it has, checks your app enables the permission or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS still can shut down services if it feels like it needs to, but it can be resumed afterward.
on `onStartCommand` you are returning **START_NOT_STICKY**
you can use which does not re start the service.
You can use **START_REDELIVER_INTENT** to save progress of your service and re start it from where it left of.
[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#START_REDELIVER_INTENT) to the docs

Answer (score 0):

A foreground service can still be killed by the OS, you have no guarantees that the service will last forever. A foreground service just makes it less likely to be killed