# Foreground service is not running in some device

Tags: java, android, foreground-service, xiaomi, oppo

I am creating a app to show push notifications to user , I have tested to run the app using Background Service for showing notifications but it didn't work for me , so I used Foreground Service. And it is working charm. But in many devices which are manufactured by vendors like OPPO , VIVO and Xiaomi when user removes the app from recent tab the foreground Service also stops working.

So why my app stops working even when I use Foreground Service.
Because as per Android documentation if you want your app to run forever you can use Foreground Service.

Isn't there any other way to run my application's Foreground Service in this type of vendors.

Please help me.

Comment: similar question： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425222/foreground-service-getting-killed-from-oreo

Comment: There are some devices that incorrectly Force Stop apps when they are swiped away from Recents.  There may not be a workaround for this problem.